# Citrix 7.6 Broker SDK C#/Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, citrix, xenapp

Has anyone worked with the Citrix 7.6 BrokerSession SDK? I can't figure out how to execute a command like this for example:

```
GetBrokerSessionCommand getCmd = new GetBrokerSessionCommand();
getCmd.AdminAddress = "citrixServer:80";
var result = getCmd.Invoke();
```

This gives me an error message saying: "Cmdlets derived from PSCmdlet cannot be invoked directly.

In the earlier 6.5 SDK I could do like this:

```
string[] servers = new string[] { };
GetXAWorkerGroupByName workerGroup = new GetXAWorkerGroupByName();
workerGroup.WorkerGroupName = new string[] { workerGroupName };
workerGroup.ComputerName = XenAppController;
foreach (XAWorkerGroup _workerGroup in CitrixRunspaceFactory.DefaultRunspace.ExecuteCommand(workerGroup))
                {
                    servers = _workerGroup.ServerNames;
                }

            return servers;
```

But now the CitrixRunspaceFactory no longer exists? 
I want to avoid executing the command with the Powershell class and Powershell.Create() for the simple reason of handling exceptions in a simpler way.

Comment: I would love it if someone knew anything about the SDK in 7.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citrix 7.6 cmdlets derived not from Cmdlet class but from PSCmdlet. So they much more binded to the PowerShell engine and must be invoked inside it:

```
    Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runSpace.Open();
    PSSnapInException psex;
    runSpace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Citrix.Broker.Admin.V2", out psex);
    Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

    Command getSession = new Command("Get-BrokerSession");
    getSession.Parameters.Add("AdminAddress", "SERVERNAME");
    pipeline.Commands.Add(getSession);

    Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
```

AFAIK good times of strongly typed classes in Citrix SDK are gone.